# Create Object name using Loop from arraylist

Tags: java, android, loops, treeview

I'm looking for something to crate TreeView in my application but i'm unable to create Node object using loop.

i just want to create dynamically object name which i can use in my TreeView.

Here is the library which i used in my application.
[TreeView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6779)

```
for(int i = 0; i< arrId.size(); i++){
        final Node i = new Node(getNodeText(i));
    }
```

Also i try to do this one and i'm getting error is "node" variable is already declared in scope.

```
for(int loopI = 0; loopI< arrId.size(); loopI++){
            String node = "node"+arrId.get(loopI);
            final Node node = new Node(getNodeText(loopI));
        }
```

Here Is the Static Code that working good.

```
 final Graph graph = new Graph();
    final Node node1 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node2 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node3 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node4 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node5 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node6 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node8 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node7 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node9 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node10 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node11 = new Node(getNodeText());
    final Node node12 = new Node(getNodeText());

    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node3);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node4);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node5);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node6);
    graph.addEdge(node6, node7);
    graph.addEdge(node6, node8);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node9);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node10);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node11);
    graph.addEdge(node11, node12);
```

Comment: what do you want to do with `Node i`?

Comment: @user7294900  without it i can't create dynamically TreeView

Comment: Show enough code so that it is clear how these `for` loops matter to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should override method `getNodeText()` because you want to pass the argument. Or just dont pass the argument like `getNodeText(i)` because this method already have counter.

```
private String getNodeText() {
    return "Node " + nodeCount++;
}
```

Comment: Thank. but i want using my 'id' which coming from database.

Comment: So try to @Override `getNodeText()` function to `getNodeText(databaseId)`, pass id argument from database and return `"Node" + databaseId;` instead of `"Node " + nodeCount++;`

Comment: no it's just a text which show on node . i want to create node object dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that you should be using some sort of collection here.  Consider the following:

```
final List<Node> allNodes = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i < arrId.size(); i++) {
    Node node = new Node(getNodeText(i));
    allNodes.add(node);
}
```

Then, when you want to build your tree view:

```
final Graph graph = new Graph();
graph.addEdge(node.get(0), node.get(1));
graph.addEdge(node.get(0), node.get(2));
graph.addEdge(node.get(0), node.get(3));
graph.addEdge(node.get(1), node.get(4));
graph.addEdge(node.get(1), node.get(5));
graph.addEdge(node.get(5), node.get(6));
graph.addEdge(node.get(5), node.get(7));
graph.addEdge(node.get(3), node.get(8));
graph.addEdge(node.get(3), node.get(9));
graph.addEdge(node.get(3), node.get(10));
graph.addEdge(node.get(10), node.get(11));
```

The idea here is that you should not be trying to number your variables yourself.  Most of the time, when you have this need, you should instead be using a collection.  Most list implementations have a built in counter which can be used to number the elements.

Comment: Hey can you more help me because i have two column in database which one  for 'id' and another is 'parentId' . i want when first 'graph.addEdge' argument is 'parentId' and another will be 'id'.
 your code will work but for me i want node with 'id' so i can match with my 'parentId'